# jquery siblings attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to store the `href` value in the `.mp3Logo` `div` to a variable. I want to store it by clicking on a `.startb`. The value in `musicLink` is being stored as undefined. Why?

Javascript

```
$('.startb').click(function() {
  var musicLink = $(this).siblings('.mp3Logo').attr('href');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="audioContainer">
  <div class="audioTitle"></div>
  <div class="playerHolder">
    <div class="startb" id="startb26" rel="Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3"><img src="dbs/images/start.png" width="40" height="40" /></div>
    <div class="flashObj" id="test26"></div>
    <div class="mp3Logo"><a href="Audio/004_IAM_God_is_Love.mp3"><img src="dbs/images/mp3_off.gif"/></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The rel attribute holds your a[href] value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The div does not have an `href` attribute. You need to descend into the anchor.

```
$(this).siblings('.mp3Logo').find('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.startb').click(function() {
    var musicLink = $(this).siblings('.mp3Logo').children().attr('href');
});
```

or even easier as I commented that the div.startb rel attribute holds the a[href] value.

```js
 $('.startb').click(function() {
        var musicLink = $(this).attr('rel');
    });
```

Div is not a href so your were receiving an undefined href.

[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Answer (score 0):

remove the var

```
$('.startb').click(function() {
    musicLink = $(this).siblings('.mp3Logo').find('a').attr('href');
});
```

you are making it local in scope

and you need to look into the div to find the a which actually has the href

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the solutions proposed above is called for. Yes, musicLink is undefined because your use of "var" makes it local in scope. Either write "var musicLink;" in the desired scope before your .click() or remove the "var" to make your variable global. See [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript) for a good explanation of the scope chain in JavaScript.

You're also looking for href in the wrong place. This should work:

```
$('.startb').click(function() {
    musicLink = $(this).siblings('.mp3Logo').children('a').attr('href');
});
```